# Existence of holomorphic function with a sequence of zeros in the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots

The question is :
Prove that there exists a holomorphic function $f$ on the open unit disc $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| <1\}$ with the properties that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1-1/n)=1$ for every integer $n$ greater than $1$.

My first idea was to use the general version of the Weierstrass factorization theorem to say that there exists a holomorphic function, $g(z)$ in $\mathbb{D}$ with zeros at $z_n = 1-1/n$ and no other zeros. Thus $g(z)+1$ is a candidate for our function. However we need to ensure that $g(0) = -1$. I don't know how.

**Note:** If such a function exists then it will be unbounded as for bounded holomorphic functions in $\mathbb{D}$ with zeros at $z_n$, $\sum (1-|z_n|)$ must converge.

Comment: From where this question is collected?

Comment: This is a question from an old qualifying exam.

Comment: Indian exam ? If yes please mention in the heading such that we can get it easily.

Comment: No. It is an old PhD qualifying exam question, not from any Indian university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is much simpler. Take $g = f-1.$ then that function has to have zeros at your $1-1/n$ and $-1$ at $0.$ Take the Weierstrass function $f$. It will have zeros where it is supposed to and some random value $v$ at $0.$ Now, just divide by $-v.$

Comment: I am sorry, but can you elaborate a little bit. From the Mittag-Leffler's theorem I can definitely guarantee the existence of such a holomorphic function but additionally I can only specify the poles (none in this case) and the principal part of the Laurent series of the function. How does that help in specifying the value at $z=0$.

Comment: Mittag-leffler actually is not the right thing, see the edit.

Comment: What if $v$ is zero... (then you can work things out, agreed)

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry to have got stuck at such a simple observation. I was thinking of composing with some transformation to force the origin to go to zero and all that complicated stuff.

Comment: @Seub notice that the weierstrass function ONLY has zeros at the prescribed points -- I did think of that :)

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm wondering: can you improve Wierstrass' theorem to prescribe arbitrary values on a closed discrete set?

Comment: Yes, this is the general Mittag-Leffler theorem, but notice that the OP's set is NOT discrete (though it is discrete in the interior...)

Comment: Yes it is discrete!

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581113/specifying-a-holomorphic-function-by-a-sequence-of-values

Comment: Thanks for the link! I assume it works for any closed discrete set in an open set.

Comment: Yes, I believe so, though the general machine spawned by this is the whole subject of sheaves (see Grauert and Remmert, etc).

Answer (score 3):

What about
$$ f(z) = 1 + \frac{1}{\pi z} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{1 - z}\right) $$

Comment: That is indeed an elegant example. Did you just come up with the function just using the periodic property of sine function or is there a more systematic process?

Comment: Well, $\sin$ is a handy example of a holomorphic function with a nice infinite set of zeros. So first I thought of $\sin(\pi/(1-z))$ (so that $1/(1-z) = n$ when $z = 1 - 1/n$). Then I realized that we can correct this so that it satisfies $f(0) = 1$. Oh wait I got it wrong, I'll edit.

Comment: So no, no systematic process. Although from a practical point of view, it often works to cook something up with $\sin$ in exercises ;)

Comment: Yes it indeed does. Thank you for the insight. By the way, your first solution was an example of the function zero at the points $1-1/n$ and $-1$ at the origin. Its an equivalent solution. :)